# Stopping a blinking cursor at end of css animation

Tags: html, css, animation

I guys I have tried a lot of things that didn't work. I have a css animation with a blinking cursor. I am trying to use it in this game I'm developing.

Link to game for visual reference: https://code.sololearn.com/WF65X6DEns7o/#css

+++

so here is the code that is a problem

HTML:

```
   <div id = "Header"> <b>Real Estate Agent</b> </div>
```

CSS:

```
#Header{
font-size:50px; color:darkOrange; text-shadow:3px 3pxblack;
overflow:hidden; 
letter-spacing: .15em;
animation: typing 3.5s steps(60, end), blink-caret .65s step-end infinite; 
white-space: nowrap; 
border-right: .15em solid orange;
width:500px;
}

 @keyframes typing {
  from { width: 0 }
   to { width: 500px }
   }

@keyframes blink-caret {
from, to { border-color: orange }
 50% { border-color: transparent; }
   }
```

+++++++++++++

currently the cursor blinks until all the text is done typing and then it keeps blink at the end of the words.

How can i make the cursor stop blinking at the end of the animation and stop the animation cycle.

As i have said i have tried a few things and nothing is working.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the `infinite` with `8` (*experiment with the value to your liking*) and set the initial color of the border to `transparent`.

```
animation: typing 3.5s steps(60, end), blink-caret .65s step-end 8; 
white-space: nowrap; 
border-right: .15em solid transparent;
```

This way it will blink 8 times and then become invisible.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the word `infinite` from the animation for #Header:

```
animation: typing 3.5s steps(60, end), blink-caret .65s step-end;
```

Comment: i tried this but it doesnt work... if i remove the infinite then the cursor stops blinkingjust stops at the end of the element as solid line but it still visible

Comment: Well, that was the question :) To let it stop blinking.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `infinite` like this:

```
animation: typing 3.5s steps(60, end), blink-caret .65s step-end;
```

Comment: i tried this but it doesnt work... if i remove the infinite then the cursor stops blinkingjust stops at the end of the element as solid line but it still visible

Comment: But you wanted "How can i make the cursor stop blinking". Right?

Comment: Yes but i want it to disappear -- so it must blink during the animation but disappear at the end of the animation

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#Header{
    font-size:50px; color:darkOrange; text-shadow:3px 3px black; overflow: hidden; letter-spacing: .15em;
    animation: typing 3.5s steps(60, end), blink-caret .65s step-end 5; white-space: nowrap; 
    width:500px;
}

@keyframes typing {
  from { width: 0 }
  to { width: 500px }
}

@keyframes blink-caret {
  from, to { border-color: transparent; }
  50% { border-right: .15em solid orange; }
}
```

Comment: thank you - it was already solved buddy. appreciate the help though

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem for a switch-toggle.
The blinking-cursor mart the position in the text, where the next character will be typed. I solved the problem by making the caret transparent (definition of my lable-class):

```
caret-color: transparent;
```